# Should I add an extra date column?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

TL;DR: I have a column with a timestamp column. I want to filter by a particular date. Should I add a date coulmn?

```
id(AI/PK)    some    fields    timestamp    *date?*
```

So the query with only a timestamp colum would be something like

```
SELECT ? 
FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = '2015' AND MONTH(timestamp) = '04' AND DAY(timestamp) = '1'
```

vs a query with an additional date column

```
SELECT ? FROM [TABLE] WHERE date = date('04-01-2015')?
```

I'm currently in a planning and design phase of my project. But it will be a very huge table in production. So the cons of having a date column are obviously the increased size of the table. I guess the con of not having a date column would be decreased performance. No?

Well I'm not sure if it's that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  You can do:

```
SELECT ?
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE date(timestamp) = '2015-04-01'
```

Or, if you want the query to use an index:

```
SELECT ?
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE timestamp >= '2015-04-01' AND
      timestamp < date_add('2015-04-01', interval 1 day);
```